# How do i use Samba Share ACL & Posix ACL together on linux

Tags: linux, arch-linux, samba, cifs

I'm looking Share ACL & Posix ACL (File permission) combination examples.   But I couldn't find an example how can i use both together...

I was using "chmod A+" on solaris. What I should use on linux?
I want to build my ACL's exactly same as Windows ACL's.

Do you know or have any example?

Samba Version: 4.6.5
OS: Arch-linux

My smb.conf;

```
[Global]
  netbios name = NETBIOSM
  workgroup = TM
  realm = TM.PVT
  server string = %h TM Host
  security = ads
  encrypt passwords = yes

  idmap config SM.PVT : backend = ad
  idmap config SM.PVT : range = 10000-20000
  idmap config SM.PVT : schema_mode = rfc2307
  idmap config * : range = 8000-9000

  winbind use default domain = Yes
  winbind enum users = Yes
  winbind enum groups = Yes
  winbind nested groups = Yes
  winbind refresh tickets = yes
  winbind offline logon = yes
  winbind cache time = 300

  template shell = /bin/bash
  template homedir = /home/%D/%U

  preferred master = no
  dns proxy = no
  wins server = tmdc.tm.pvt
  wins proxy = no

#  acl group control = yes

  load printers = no
  debug level = 3
  use sendfile = no

  vfs objects = acl_xattr
  map acl inherit = yes
  store dos attributes = yes

[test]
 comment = ACL Test
 path = /testPool/smbtest
 valid users = TM.PVT\administrator TM.PVT\user1 SM.PVT\user2
 admin users = TM.PVT\administrator
 public = no
 writable = yes
 inherit permissions = yes
 inherit acls = yes
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally found a few explanations!
I wonder why developer thinks we already know everything.
If you read the links below you will find the answer to everything you wonder about this topic and history of development.

https://www.ja-ki.eu/2016/09/19/gedaechtnisstuetze-acls-mit-zfs-on-linux-und-samba-4-5/

http://cuddletech.com/?p=23

http://cuddletech.com/?p=459

Comment: The first link is broken... neither of the other two links make any mention of Samba.